# is it ok to have php.ini display_errors=On production environment

Tags: php, php-ini

On production environment

I have check.php

```
<?php
test();
?>
```

When doing

```
curl -v http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test.php
```

If php.ini on my production environment has

```
display_errors=Off
```

and I get below header

```
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2015 08:10:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

* Closing connection #0
```

If I change it to

```
display_errors=On
```

I get the below header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2015 08:13:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Content-Length: 119
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function test() in <b>/var/www/html/check.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
* Closing connection #0
```

So, when I have

```
display_errors=Off
```

I get

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

So, to avoid 500 Internal Server Error, I need to have display_errors=On

Is it okay to have

```
display_errors=On
```

on production environment?

Comment: I'm confused, why do you want the production server to show "call to undefined function..." ? Surely you want to fix this issue in development? display_errors=On in a production environment is not a good idea as it could give malicious parties clues that could help them exploit your service/system.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with a `500 Internal Server Error`?! That's exactly what you experience. Your script is wrong and dies a sudden death; that's an internal error in your server. A `500` response signals to the client that there was an error which is not the fault of the client, so the client should not use whatever response it received and maybe try again later. That's exactly what must happen in this scenario and that's what `display_errors=off` does.